# Open native maps app to show route direction in WIndows8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to open native maps app to show the route directions? Need to do this for windows 8 app, and assume it should work for windows 8.1 also in c#

Or is there any maps link uri protocol (similar to mailto:) which can be used to implement this and launched using `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bingmaps: protocol documented at [URI scheme for Bing Maps app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx)

Example: bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076ss